# Get number of tabs opened with Bulk URL Opener using AutoHotkey

Tags: javascript, autohotkey

I use an extension in Chrome (Bulk URL Opener). This extension opens multiple links at an interval of seconds. It also opens a new tab (*x1*) that has play and pause buttons. When pressing the play button, the extension starts opening new tabs to the right and keeps opening. When pressing the pause button, it stops the opening of a new tab.

What I want AutoHotkey to do here is to read the number of tabs opened in Chrome. If there are less than 10 tabs, then I want AutoHotkey to give input to the *x1* tab and start the opening of the new tab. Also, if the number of opened tabs is more than 12, then I want AutoHotkey to give input again to the *x1* tab and stop the opening of a new tab.

Basically, I want only 10 or 12 tabs to be opened in Chrome at once and if I close a tab or two I want a new tab to be automatically opened. Is there a way that I can achieve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Read this source: https://dev.to/dcodeyt/send-data-between-tabs-with-javascript-2oa

Initializing a channel happens like this:

```
const channel = new BroadcastChannel("my-channel");
```

This is how you can receive a message:

```
channel.addEventListener("message", e => {
    console.log(e.data);
});
```

This is how you can post a message

```
channel.postMessage("Hello world");
```

Now, knowing all these, let's see the

## Solution

If you open tabs, you will open some URL for each of them. Assuming that you are in control of the source-code of the pages you open, you can do the following:

- Initialize a channel both on your main tab and the open tabs
- Create a `message` event listener both on your main tab and the open tabs
- Whenever you might want to open tabs, post messages to the sub-tabs and see how many responses you get

Example

### Child event listener

```
const channel = new BroadcastChannel("my-channel");
channel.addEventListener("message", e => {
    if (e.data === "ping") channel.postMessage("pong");
});
```

### Main event listener

```
var pongCount = 0;
var pongLimit = 12;
const channel = new BroadcastChannel("my-channel");
channel.addEventListener("message", e => {
    if (e.data === "pong") pongCount++;
});
```

### Tick

```
setInterval(function() {
    pongCount = 0;
    channel.postMessage("ping");
    setTimeout(function() {
        for (let pongIndex = pongCount + 1; pongIndex < pongLimit; pongIndex++) {
            //open a tab
        }
    }, 100);
}, 1000);
```

Note that the tick code needs to be in the main tab

EDIT

It seems that there is no access to the pages that are being loaded. If that's the case, one can implement a proxy app that will transmit the request to the target pages to bypass Chrome's restrictions and have wrapper pages where you have full access in terms of source-code and therefore that would be able to send and receive messages.

Alternatively one can use the chrome.tabs extension, like

```
chrome.tabs.query({windowType:'normal'}, function(tabs) {
    console.log('Number of open tabs in all normal browser windows:',tabs.length);
});
```

But for that purpose, the given extension will be needed to be installed: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/

Comment: I don't have the source code!!. what i am basically doing is, i am trying to open multiple links using an extension in chrome. And all that links open in new tabs but the problem is it keeps opening which causes the chrome to lag. so i want to open only 10 or 12 links at once and the rest to open once the previous tabs are closed!!. Hope u are understanding

Comment: @BillyMiller I understand your problem-statement, but the info you intend to gather, that is, the open tabs is somewhat of a private information. For example why would I as a user trust your extension with the number of tabs being opened? So I guess you will not be able to directly get this information. If you are writing a web-crawler, for example and you run it in chrome, then you may create a proxy site that you have the source-code for and that transmits the request to the target on server-side.

Comment: @BillyMiller also, if the user opened some other tabs as well, it will be difficult to differentiate between the tabs opened by your app and the tabs opened by the user. So, in order to make that distinction you will need to get active responses from your tabs.

Comment: @BillyMiller if you can convince your users to install further extensions, the chrome.tabs (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/) may be helpful.

Comment: @BillyMiller I have added further information to the answer

Comment: It seems that it's not possible to get that info out of chrome even with the chrome.tabs API

Comment: @BillyMiller then you could create a webserver on your own and request only your webserver, so Javascript messaging will be available. And your webserver, on its turn will send requests to the actual target sites and render their response. It should work and you can bypass the browser restrictions this way. I have applied this approach to cope with somewhat similar issues.